# Parse the duration of a WMA (ASF) music file

Tags: asf

I'm working on a tool that generates a file for use in the Original Xbox's Music menu. Put simply, it grabs a bunch of music files in **WMA** (only!) format, then generates a soundtrack description file (`ST.DB`), and a filesystem, based on those songs.

That soundtrack description file has a field that allows storing the duration or length of a song, this is what I'm trying to accomplish.

I've searched around the internet for some kind of description or documentation on the WMA format, so I can write a small tool that parses just the duration of the music in the file. But I haven't found much, most people seem to use Windows SDK calls, which is completely overkill for my purposes. Plus, my aim is to make this tool cross-platform, so, using Windows SDKs isn't an option.

I've tried using ffmpeg/ffprobe, both of which do the job, but there are drawbacks:

- Their outputs aren't optimal (I'd have to parse them afterwards)
- I would like not to rely on external tools

Any documentation or sample code would be extremely useful, anyways, thanks in advance!

Comment: https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/font-classtopic-s-color00c1dewmafont-format-file-header-parsing_8_8_32044736.html all you have to do is to read certain bytes like with any file format header. Also here https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000027.shtml

Comment: If ffmpeg/ffprobe does everything you want ... then why don't you just look at the source code: https://github.com/FFmpeg/?  Alternatively, if the information you're looking for is encoded directly in the .wma file, you might want to investigate the WMA format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Audio

Comment: @paulsm4 isn't FFmpeg also an overkill?)